# White space between actionbar and statusbar

Tags: android, android-layout

as you can see in the picture below, the white space lays between status bar and actionbar. I normally include `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` with TextView and then I set supportActionbar in MainActivity.

This bug happens only on Sony phone with android 6.0

[image: doubled actionbar]

Comment: Share your xml code

Comment: Android 6 has a circle home icon. The pic you posted is from 4

Comment: I would say its at least android 5.0 since it has colored statusbar, it's phone from one of our customers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    if(actionBar !=null)
    {
        actionBar.hide();
    }
```